# AngularJS ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I created an object named `Item1` and I want to create 2 subfields called `field1` and `field2` as given at the HTML below:

For field1:

```
<input ng-model="myItem.field1"></input>
```

For field2:

```
<select ng-model="myItem.field2" ng-init="myItem.field2=fieldOptions[0]" ng-options="val for myItem.field2 in fieldOptions" ng-change="changed(myItem)"></select>
```

Checkout that, I want to initialise my `select form` to the first element of an array called `fieldOptions`. I defined my field options as follows:

```
$scope.fieldOptions = [ 'opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3' ];
```

When I run this code I have the following error:

```
Error: [ngOptions:iexp] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ngOptions/iexp?p0=myItem.field2NaNor%20myItem.field2%in%20policyNames&p1=%3Cselect%20ng-model%3D%22myItem.field2%22%20ng-init%3D%22myItem.field2%3DfieldOptions%5B0%5D%22%20ng-options%3D%22myItem.field2%for%20myItem.field2%in%20policyNames%22%20ng-change%3D%changed(myItem)%22%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-valid%22%3E
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:6:450
    at n (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:205:427)
    at link (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:207:462)
    at J (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:53:345)
    at f (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:46:399)
    at f (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:46:416)
    at J (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:53:286)
    at f (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:46:399)
    at f (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular.min.js:46:416) angular.js:9778
(anonymous function) angular.js:9778
(anonymous function) angular.js:7216
J angular.js:6582
f angular.js:5986
f angular.js:5989
J angular.js:6573
f angular.js:5986
f angular.js:5989
(anonymous function) angular.js:5891
(anonymous function) angular.js:1384
h.$eval angular.js:12412
h.$apply angular.js:12510
(anonymous function) angular.js:1382
d angular.js:3869
$b.c angular.js:1380
$b angular.js:1394
Wc angular.js:1307
(anonymous function) angular.js:21459
fire jquery-2.1.0.js:3047
self.fireWith jquery-2.1.0.js:3159
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-2.1.0.js:3365
completed
```

As far as I understand, the AngularJs compiler doesn't like `ng-options` definition. Because, when replace `myItem.field2` with some other field name called `otherfieldname` as follows:

```
<select ng-model="otherFieldName" ng-init="otherFieldName=fieldOptions[0]" ng-options="otherFieldName for otherFieldName in fieldOptions" ng-change="changed(myItem)"></select>
```

It works as expected. Somehow, when I use a dot separated model name, it causes an error.

I also checked the [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) document for the directives designed for `Select` menu. In the `ng-options` part, the following forms are said to be valid for array data sources:

- `label` `for` `value` `in` `array`
- `select` `as` `label` `for` `value` `in` `array`
- `label` `group` `by` `group` `for` `value` `in` `array`
- `select` `as` `label` `group` `by` `group` `for` `value` `in` `array` `track` `by` `trackexpr`

As far as I understand, the `label for value in array` fits for me. Here, `Array` is `$scope.fieldOptions` in my case. But what shall `label` and `value` should be? Do they have to be the same or different? And why shouldn't I use dot separated models for `label` and `value` (*i.e.* myItem).

Do you have any idea?

JSFiddle is provided [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/3HeFB/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are confusing `ng-model` and `ng-options`

`ng-options` is used to construct the options only. The syntax can be a bit confusing but it is telling angular how to look at your array.

With a simple one dimensional array what you want is:

`ng-options="val for val in fieldOptions"`

Where `fieldOptions` is the scope array.

The variable name `val` can be anything you want like `foo for foo in fieldOptions`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3HeFB/9/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.  The main problem seems to be that you are treating the list items as if they are an array of objects ("field1" and "field2"), but when you create the list, it's just an array of strings.

I also see problems with what you are doing with ng-init, and I'm not sure ng-model or your ng-change function are doing what you want.

I fixed up your fiddle to what I think you were going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/3HeFB/10/

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    console.log("Main Controller loaded.");

    //create objects instead of strings
    $scope.fieldOptions = [{
        field1: 'opt1',
        field2: 'opt1Text'
    }, {
        field1: 'opt2',
        field2: 'opt2Text'
    }];    
    //default the var you use in ng-model to first item
    $scope.myItem = $scope.fieldOptions[0];
    console.log($scope.fieldOptions[0]);
    //change function does not get parameter passed
    $scope.changed = function () {
        console.log("Field2 changed.");
        console.log($scope.myItem);
    };
}]);
```